# How to add extra atrributes in a FOR XML PATH statement

Tags: sql-server-2005, attributes, for-xml-path

Is there a way to add an additional attribute as below?

Before...

```
  <Event id="CE1127552523644210147">
    <Title>General Surgery Orange Rotation </Title>
    <Duration>671</Duration>
    <InstructionalMethod>Clinical Rotation</InstructionMethod>
  </Event>
```

After:

```
  <Event id="CE1127552523644210147">
    <Title>General Surgery Orange Rotation </Title>
    <Duration>671</Duration>
    <InstructionalMethod Primary='True'>Clinical Rotation</InstructionMethod>
  </Event>
```

Original Query:

```
select 
    id as '@id',
    Title,
    Duration,
    InstructionalMethod
from MyTable
for XML PATH ('Event'), ROOT('Events')
```

Based on search on Stack I did try this but no data returned for the element.

```
select 
    id as '@id',
    Title,
    Duration,
    'True' AS 'InstructionalMethod/@Primary'
from mytable
for XML PATH ('Event'), ROOT('Events'), TYPE
```

Result:

```
  <Event id="CE1127552523644210147">
    <Title>General Surgery Orange Rotation </Title>
    <Duration>671</Duration>
    <InstructionalMethod Primary="True" />
  </Event>
```

Thanks for your help.

Brian

Comment: As an aside, I recommend against using `'single quotes'` to delimit column aliases; [this syntax has been deprecated](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb510662%28SQL.100%29.aspx) (search for the first instance of "literal" on that page). You should use `"double quotes"` or, preferably, `[square brackets]` when a column alias needs a delimiter.

Comment: Thanks Aaron for your tips Aaron.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You're close - but if you want the element, you have to have that line in there, too!

Try this:

```
SELECT
    id as '@id',
    Title,
    Duration,
    'True' AS 'InstructionalMethod/@Primary',
    InstructionalMethod   -- add this line to get the actual value as element
FROM 
    dbo.mytable
FOR XML PATH ('Event'), ROOT('Events'), TYPE
```